# Prove that $1- x^T Qx- b^Tx$ is not convex

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

$Q$ is positive definite ($Q>0$). I want to prove that problem $P$ is **not** convex. How can I do it?

[image]

> Hint: Complete the square.

Why can't I say that $1-x^TQx-b^Tx \leq 0$ is a concave function?

Comment: What then ? @RodrigodeAzevedo

Comment: How does it help to proof ? I can't understand @RodrigodeAzevedo

Comment: And ? I want to proof that P not convex. @RodrigodeAzevedo

Comment: How do you define convexity of (P)?

Comment: all function need to be convex in conical form. @gerw

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f(x)=1-x^TQx-b^Tx$ is convex. Then $f(\frac{x+y}{2}) \le \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$ for all $x,y$. For $y=0$ this gives:

$x^TQx \le -2$, which is absurd !

Comment: How can I use the hint ? @Fred. I need to proof that P is not convex

Comment: What is $P$ ? You have asked: why is $f$ not convex ? I gave you a proof (without the hint).

Comment: P is a optimization problem that contain f @Fred